# unexpected eof while parsing_list

Tags: python, list

```
movies=["a","b","c",[1,2,3,['jia','yi','bing']],"d"]
print(movies([3][3][1])
```

I want to print 'yi' in this case.
Just started learning python by myself.

Comment: `print(movies[3][3][1])`, watch the parenthesis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code `movies(...)` tries to call/invoke the object stored in `movies` as if it was a function. Since a list is not callable, you will get an exception.

To get items from a list (or any other subscriptable) you have to use square brackets right after the identificator. Do:

```
movies[3][3][1]
```

Within your print statement:

```
print(movies[3][3][1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra open parenthesis before the brackets. It should be:

```
print(movies[3][3][1])
```